# Get window handles for a given process in Linux/Ubuntu with python

Tags: python, linux

Is it possible to get the window handle (and then close that window) given a process ID **in Linux**?

I want to close a dialog that launched a process (a python extension inside Inkscape) but the process itself is not passed any info about the dialog that launched it (its parent process is `systemd`)

Ideally in python, otherwise pointers to a solution that I can research further are fine too.